# Find values in array depending on a pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, find, pattern-matching

I have an array:

```
var videoSources = ["0000.mp4", "0015.mp4", "0030.mp4", "0045.mp4", "0100.mp4"];
```

I would play videos based on current time; mp4 are recorded every 15minutes;

```
if time = 0044 play 0030.mp4
```

So I need something like a pattern `[0-15]` to find and play correct video.
Here function to play video at the moment:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
// listener function changes src
function myNewSrc() {
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.load();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest parseing the file name to an integer and then finding if a minute mark is within the range of the file:

```js
var videoSources = 
  ["0000.mp4", 
  "0015.mp4", 
  "0030.mp4", 
  "0045.mp4", 
  "0100.mp4"]

var getTimestamp = (ts, sources) =>
  sources.find(name => {
    const startStr = name.split(".")[0];      // e.g.: "0015"
    const startMin = parseInt(startStr, 10);  // e.g.: 15
    const endMin = startMin + 15;
    
    return ts >= startMin && ts < endMin; 
  });

console.log(getTimestamp(44, videoSources));
```

If the ranges aren't guaranteed to be 15 minutes, you could do a "look ahead" to find the *end* of a range. In my current example, I've hardcoded it to be 15 minutes, and expect the file name to be the *start* of the file.

*Edit: to support hours and minutes*

```js
var videoSources = 
  ["0000.mp4", 
  "0015.mp4", 
  "0030.mp4", 
  "0045.mp4", 
  "0100.mp4",
  "1145.mp4",
  "1230.mp4",
  "1245.mp4"]

var getTimestamp = (h, m, sources) =>
  sources
    .sort()
    .find(name => {
      const hours = parseInt(name.slice(0, 2), 10);
      const minutesStart = parseInt(name.slice(2, 4), 10);
      const minutesEnd = minutesStart + 15;
      
      return h <= hours && m >= minutesStart && m < minutesEnd; 
    });

console.log(getTimestamp(12, 44, videoSources));
```

Comment: it works but I also need hour to be parsed because it will record for the whole day. So I will have: 
'code`
var videoSources = [
"0000.mp4", 
"0015.mp4", 
"0030.mp4", 
"0045.mp4", 
"0100.mp4", 
"0115.mp4", 
"0130.mp4", 
"0145.mp4", 
"0200.mp4", 
"0215.mp4", 
"0230.mp4", 
"0245.mp4", 
"0300.mp4", 
"0315.mp4", 
"0330.mp4", 
"0345.mp4", 
"0400.mp4", 
"0415.mp4", 
"0430.mp4", 
"0445.mp4", 
"0500.mp4", 
"0515.mp4", 
"0530.mp4",
ETC....

Comment: If the format is always `HHmm`, you can use `slice(0, 2)` and `slice(2, 4)` to get the hours and minutes individually. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: your code works great! But I got current time stored into 'time' variable in this format 1230, I tried this below but no success:
`function addZero(i) { if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i; }
    return i;}
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
   etc...
    var time = Number(strtime);
    var getTimestamp = (ts, sources) =>
    sources.find(name => {
    const startStr = name.split(".")[0];   
    const startMin = parseInt(startStr, 10); 
    const endMin = startMin + 15;
    return ts >= startMin && ts < endMin; });}
document.write(getTimestamp(time, videoSources));`

Answer (score 0):

You could map your times array and time to numbers and then use `findIndex` method to return index of correct time element from array.

```js
var videoSources = ["0000.mp4", "0015.mp4", "0030.mp4", "0045.mp4", "0100.mp4"]

const getIndex = (arr, time) => {
  time = parseInt(time);
  arr = arr.map(e => parseInt(e.split('.')[0]));
  return arr.findIndex((e, i) => time >= e && !arr[i + 1] || time < arr[i + 1]);
}

console.log(getIndex(videoSources, "0044"))
console.log(getIndex(videoSources, "0015"))
console.log(getIndex(videoSources, "0099"))
console.log(getIndex(videoSources, "0120"))
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand your logic